# Not sure why I am getting a segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, malloc, dynamic-arrays

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** zeros(int rows, int cols) {
  int ** array;

  array = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));

  for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++) {
    array[i] = (int *)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
  }

  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      array[r][c] = 0;
    }
  }

  return array;

}

int main(void) {
  // declare variables
  int rows = 3;
  int cols = 3;

  int ** zeroArray = zeros(rows, cols);

  for (int r = 0; r < rows; r++) {
    for (int c = 0; c < cols; c++) {
      printf("%d ",zeroArray[r][c]);
      } 
    printf("\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

I have this code and when the value of rows is greater than 4 I get a segmentation fault. cols can be anything and it works, I've tested where the pointers are adressed to and everything seems fine but it just breaks when rows is 5 or more.

Comment: array = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof( int * ));

Comment: To avoid simple typo-bugs like this, it's better to use the variable name instead of a type when calling `malloc`, i.e. do `array = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);` and `array[i] = malloc(cols * sizeof *array[i]);`

Comment: You used the wrong `sizeof` argument when allocating `array`.  It should be `array = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));`, i.e. `int *` rather than `int`.  But you really only need `array = malloc(rows * sizeof(int *));` (the cast is unnecessary).

Comment: Use this idiom: `array = malloc(n * sizeof *array);`, where `n` is the number of elements in the array. Casting the return value of `malloc` is unnecessary in C.

Comment: @M.NejatAydin No idiom can save the programmer from themselves. It's as easy to make the mistake of typing `sizeof(int)` as to type `sizeof(array)`.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
array = (int **)malloc(rows * sizeof(int));

for (int i = 0; i < rows;i++) {
  array[i] = (int *)malloc(cols * sizeof(int));
}
```

is wrong, it assumes `sizeof(int)` to be equal to `sizeof (int *)` which is not a good move on modern systems.

Make it:

```
array = malloc(rows * sizeof *array);
```

that removes the manual "guessed" type, and simply uses the size of whatever `array` points at, which is of course `int *`.